# Base de datos en Mongodb, agregar infomacion (Robo 3T)

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, insert

Estoy trabajando con mongodb, tengo una coleccion de usuarios, pero la misma esta vacia, quiero agregar usuario a la bd, uso Robo 3T, antes lo podia hacer tranquilamente, iba Robo 3T, me conectaba, iba a la coleccion de usuarios e insertaba un documento, por ejemplo algo asi:

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("59c1137fb9f9ab3a026e5e17"),
            "temporarytoken" : "false",
            "name" : "Alex Pepe",
            "email" : "alex@ejemplo.com",
            "password" : "$2a$10$FjiQdyc8Uzem9PVDQXwg/eI8.FeKFD7D7maodEobB4O/3XT6vnm46",
            "username" : "alexPepe",
            "rota" : [ ],
            "holidays" : [ ],
            "pref" : [
                    {
                            "timePref1" : {
                                    "value" : "N/A",
                                    "name" : "N/A"
                            },
                            "timePref2" : {
                                    "value" : "N/A",
                                    "name" : "N/A"
                            },
                            "empType" : {
                                    "value" : "FT",
                                    "name" : "Full Time"
                            },
                            "shiftPref" : {
                                    "value" : "EM",
                                    "name" : "01:45 - 06:45 (Madrugada)"
                            }
                    }
            ],
            "permission" : "admin",
            "active" : true,
            "__v" : 2
    },
```

Pero me tira error todo el tiempo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He cambiado los corchetes, agregado, quitado, no hay forma, siempre me tira un error parecido al de la foto.

Desde ya muchas gracias por lo que me puedan ayudar.

Saludos!

Comment: Hola, te recomendaría que intentes:
1) Insertar un documento mas pequeño e ir agregando los campos, para encontrar el error.  
2) Insertar el mismo documento por consola (lo sé es un horror jaja) pero para descartar errores de Robo3T.  
3) Acceder a https://jsonlint.com/ y validar el JSON.  
4) Aunque parezca una tontería a veces al pulsar execute en la consola de Robo3T creo que influye la posición donde tengas situado el puntero.
Saludos.

Comment: @JuanjooTocino he probado eso y me ha funcionado, no se exactamente que fue... pero funciona por el momento, gracias.